# Failed deployment to Ethereum mainnet ate all my ETH

Tags: go-ethereum, dapps, etherscan, hardhat, mainnet

I've been trying to deploy two contracts with proxy admins to ethereum mainnet but they kept failing due to intrinsic funds which was fine because it reverted before taking any of my ETH.

I tested on deploying on Goerli and it cost around 0.01 ETH so I thought I had more than enough ETH (0.09ETH) in my mainnet wallet.

Then one time I tried, it reverted due to 'INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS' but I checked my wallet and all my ETH was gone. Here's a my wallet on Etherscan: https://etherscan.io/address/0xe0188a3a4f6e9b6670d2b16867fbff2c46342baf

Any way some of my contract got deployed? Also any way to prevent funds being taken on failed deployments in the future?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You deployed two contracts:

First one, seems to be a Proxy [0xD1Efc239FBaa191009FdC6B575f4162d1F2041D1](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x99fe06c7b46a979266a87d76a49633612af5e9da31c22984559db4b55fbafc17)

Second one has not been verified,[0x0d29e6fF0c7EeA972F629E65e74Ee527e9B5e12C](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa30912a53345027dbba7e7388edc75ca6427584695091e273fcb0f1880689e27)

Comment: Is there any way I can use the proxy already deployed in my next deployment to save on gas fees? Hoped it would have reverted the entire deploy

Comment: yes, you can, I think you're using a deployment script, and only a few steps succeeded. So you have to continue the execution from where it stopped